# Difficulty using jQuery AJAX to retrieve data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, pear

I am trying to use the jQuery ajax api to retrieve data from a mysql database. The SQL query I am using is working correctly as I have tested it by creating a user form and traditionally `$_POST`ing its content to see if it retrieves the correct data from my database.

However, I now want to retrieve the data from my mysql table without having to reload the page using the jQuery ajax function. I am a novice when it comes to jQuery, I haven't used it much before, and I would really very much appreciate it if someone could provide me with a nice example as to how it works. I have looked online at various articles and guides and I just cannot understand it.

Here is a form:

```
<form id="restaurant_reservation">
    <label for="date">Reservation Date?</label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="yyyy-mm-dd" />

    <label for="capacity">Amount of Customers?</label>
    <input type="text" name="capacity" id="capacity" />

    <label for="license">Smoking or Non-Smoking Area?</label>

    <select id="license">
        <option value="0" id="no">Smoking</option>
        <option value="1" id="yes">Non-Smoking</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

$user_reservation_date = $_POST['user_date'];
$user_customer_amount = $_POST['customer_amount'];
$user_smoking_non_smoking = $_POST['user_smoking_selection'];

$my_query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant 
             WHERE $user_reservation_date = date_available
             AND $user_customer_amount >= max_seating
             AND $user_smoking_non_smoking = smoking_choice";

$result =& $db->query($my_query);

if (PEAR::isError($result)) {
    die($result->getMessage());
}


echo '<div id="output">';

echo'<table">';
echo '<th>restaurant name</th>';
echo '<th>Max Customer Seating</th>';
echo '<th>Smoking or Non Smoking</th>';
echo '<th>Average price per head</th>';

while($row =& $result->fetchRow()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['rest_name'].'</td>'
    echo '<td>'.$row['max_seating'].'</td>'
    echo '<td>'.$row['smoking_choice'].'</td>'
    echo '<td>'.$row['avg_price_per_head'].'</td>'
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Here is my attempt at the jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').keyup(function(){
        var user_input= $('#date').val();
    });
});

$(function(){
            $('#date').keyup(function(){

            var user_input1=$('#date').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({user_date : user_input1}),
                url: 'search.php',
                success: function(data) {
                     $('#output_div').html(data);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

I use the same code but change the #values for the other two fields from the form.

I would like to use jQuery ajax to get the input and selected values of this form and store them in a variable in my php document so that I can then use the users form data in my sql query to retrieve the appropriate restaurants.

I would really love to learn how to do this, and I would really apreciate any help. Thanks so much for reading. I'm sorry if I have been vague in describing my question properly. Thanks.

Comment: have you read `jquery.ajax` documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi, Yes I have read it over and over, but I struggle to grasp the concept of it. It seems to me that in order to make any sense of their documentation, you have to have a certain level of knowledge already on jquery. Could you help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) you go, this should prove usefull :) first hit on google 'jquery ajax tutorial for beginners'

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#restaurant_reservation').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of form submit 

 // perform an ajax request and send all your data to your script in this case 
// you would replace "yourPhpScript" the actual script name      
$.ajax({
      url: 'yourPhpScript.php',
      type: 'POST', 
      data: $('#restaurant_reservation').serialize(); // serialize your form data into key value pairs 
      success: function(data) {
        console.log( data );  // this is the response from the server and will be logged in your console. 
      }
 });
```

Then in `yourPhpScript.php` you would get the posted data

```
$date = $_POST['date']; 
$capacity = $_POST['capacity'];  // etc also your select needs a name attribute
// Then preform the mysql request and send back json encoded data or html 
so either echo "html here" 
or echo json_encode(array('data'=>'data here') );
```

Then you will see that data logged to the console on the client side. Then you can choose to append that data to a a div for example. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Hi, would i need to place a submit button in my form to make the function run?

Comment: Yes, or some way for the user to trigger a submit on the form. But a submit button would be the easiest way.

Comment: Okay thanks so much for explaining this. Another question. Can i still echo out the results as i was above in my question? I dont quite understand the code in yourPphScript.php. Sorry!

Comment: Sure, you can just echo out the results like you have in your script.

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems like a relatively simple POST request, so you could use the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shortcut function (which is itself just a wrapper to [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). You pass it the URL for your PHP script, some optional data (see the next paragraph), and an optional callback function which is executed after a successful response to the AJAX call.

To get the values selected in your form, you can use an ID selector to select the form (`$('#restaurant_reservation')`), then call the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to form a URL parameter string from those values.

The entire thing may look like this:

```
$.post('myphp.php', $('#restaurant_reservation').serialize(), function(data) {
    // do something with the response HTML
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of this at the JQuery site (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) but here, to get you going.

Here is something that should take input from an input control, send it to your script, jsp, asp, servlet or whatever, get a response and display it back on the page

JQuery stuff

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#idOfInputControl").blur(function(){
    txt=$("#idOfInputControl").val();
    $.post("yourPHPorWhateverScript.php",{queryStrParamNameYourScriptLooksFor:txt},function(result){
      $("#idOfControlToHoldTheData").html(result);
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
...
<form ...>
  <input type="text" id="idOfInputControl" />
  <div id="idOfControlToHoldTheData"></div>
...
```

In this case above, your script, servlet or whatever that receives the post, should get the param "queryStrParamNameYourScriptLooksFor" from the query string and do something with that (I guess you want to add it to an SQL Query etc.) and then return some text or HTML in the response.

There are some other answers I see (poping up all while writing this) so I imagine you will be good to go with this stuff.

Good luck